# angular 2 ng build throwing Unexpected token: name when using ng build

Tags: angular

> Error: UglifyJs Unexpected token: name (XXXXXX)
>   [vendor.73c5c777cdc2978b6b1c.bundle.js:62229,4]
>
> XXXX- IonRangeSliderModule

We tried to biuld angular using `ng build --prod --aot` its showing above error.

When we tried with ng server its working fine.

Can any one helpme on this.